# Find differences between two files in python

Tags: python, compare

I am working on a code that compares two text files in python and prints the differences between the two. I was told to use sets. Is it also possible to have a dialogue box to choose the file, instead of manually inputting file names? I am very beginner level at python, so if you could write out the code, I would really appreciate it.

File1.txt

```
hamburgers
potatoes
avocado
grapes
seaweed
```

File2.txt

```
cheeseburgers
potatoes
peanuts
grapes
seaweed
```

so I would want the code to print 
cheeseburgers, peanuts

This is what I have but not sure if it's right:

```
old_path = 'File1.txt'
new_path = 'File2.txt'

old_lines = file(old_path).read().split('\n')
new_lines = file(new_path).read().split('\n')

old_lines_set = set(old_lines)
new_lines_set = set(new_lines)

old_added = old_lines_set - new_lines_set
old_removed = new_line_set - old_lines_set

for line in old_lines:
    if line in old_added:
        print '-' , line.strip()
    elif line in old_removed:
        print '+' , line.strip()

for line in new_lines:
    if line in old added:
        print '-' , line.strip()
    elif line in old_removed:
        print '+' , line.strip ()
```

Comment: And what output you get ?

Answer (score 3):

```
doc = open(filename, 'r')
doc1 = open(filename, 'r')

f1 = [x for x in doc.readlines()]
f2 = [x for x in doc1.readlines()]

diff = [line for line in f1 if line not in f2] # lines present only in f1
diff1 = [line for line in f2 if line not in f1] # lines present only in f2

doc.close()
doc1.close()
```

Comment: Keep in mind, OP, that this is very inefficient, especially for large files.

Answer (score 2):

An easier solution, using the built-in set features:

```
a = set(['hamburgers', 'potatoes', 'avocado', 'grapes', 'seaweed'])
b = set(['cheeseburgers', 'potatoes', 'peanuts', 'grapes', 'seaweed'])
a.difference(b)
b.difference(a)
```

The set.difference() function gives you set objects again, which you can process as you want.
[I hope I am not solving homework problems for you...]

Answer (score 0):

Below Solution worked for me with my exact requirement.

```
f1=open((os.getcwd()) + "\\Test1.txt","r") 
f2=open((os.getcwd()) + "\\Test2.txt","r")

for i, j in zip(f1, f2):
    if i != j: 
        print(i.rstrip() + "\t" + j.rstrip())
f1.close() 
f2.close()
```

Output:

```
R[10]=0x8     R[10]=0x13
R[54]=0x6     R[54]=0x4
R[59]=0x18    R[59]=0x58
R[60]=0x3d    R[60]=0x4c
R[126]=0x59   R[126]=0xbd
```